# Grequests not returning all items

Tags: python, python-requests, gevent, grequests

I have the following code:

```
>>> import grequests
>>> urls=[
     'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/movies/the-legend-of-blood-castle/8d6kgwzzx9hm', 
     'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/movies/babe/8d6kgwzl64t3']
>>> rs = (grequests.get(url) for url in urls)
>>> res_items=grequests.map(rs)
>>> res_items
[<Response [200]>]
```

However, it should return:

```
[<Response [200]>, <Response [404]>]
```

But for whatever reason, it's not doing anything with the 404. Why is this so, and what do I need to do for the 404 to appear in the results?

Comment: Make sure your grequests version is up-to-date: $ sudo pip install grequests --upgrade.

Comment: Not reproducible with Python 2.7.11 and `grequests==0.3.0`